# What would be my tax liability in Zurich, Switzerland?

Tags: taxes, calculation, liability, switzerland

What would be my tax liability as a single individual, resident of Zurich (not citizen), not a member of any church, with a 90,000 Swiss Franc yearly salary? Let's just take into consideration basic deductions and nothing more. Assume a net worth of 0 Swiss Francs.

I have tried different calculators online, but they give wildly different results.

Comment: You've answered some questions, but still don't tell us if you're a Swiss citizen or what your total net worth is.

Comment: @MikeScott I added those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your numbers, expect to pay about 11% in total income taxes. Use [this calculator](https://en.comparis.ch/steuern/steuervergleich/default.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not important which citizenship you have, it is very relevant to know your type of permit in Switzerland.

Unless you have a C permit (aka residence in the sense of the Swiss laws) or are married to another Swiss resident, you will be taxed at source as long as your income is below CHF 120.000 per year.

You can find more information on this tax at source [here](https://www.stadt-zuerich.ch/fd/de/index/steuern/quellensteuer/auslaendische_arbeitnehmer.html) (it's in German but you can download a PDF in english).

You can find the current tax at source tariffs [here](http://www.steueramt.zh.ch/internet/finanzdirektion/ksta/en/spezialsteuern/quellensteuer/arbeitnehmende_arbeitgebende/tarife.html).

If you are/become a full resident or fulfill one of the other mentioned criteria, you'll be no longer taxed at source but have to hand in a tax declaration and will be taxed ex-post.

Calculating your expected taxes can be a bit tedious since there are three tax levels to be considered (federal, cantonal, communal) and they all come with different and usually progressive rates.

I really like [this](https://en.comparis.ch/steuern/steuervergleich/default.aspx) tax calculator, the results should be accurate and it's available in English.

Comment: C Visa? Do you mean a Residence Permit (C) coupled with a National Visa (D)?

Comment: My mistake... I meant permit, not visa. We used to call it visa before Switzerland joined Schengen.  That indeed would be misleading nowadays. I will edit the answer.

Comment: That calculator yields about 11% total income tax (Federal + Canton). That looks really low. Is that right? Are there payroll taxes I should be aware of?

Comment: Sounds about right. There are no other taxes but there are social insurance contributions that can add up to 15% of your gross salary. This will be stated in detail in your work contract.

Comment: Only federal and canton taxes? Did the calculator also add local taxes? These are usually about as high as the cantonal taxes, and they depend on your municipality.

Comment: No worries, the calculator takes communal taxes into account.